# How can I edit this code so that it prints the result a certain way?

Tags: python

I'm trying to get this code:

```
line = input("String: ")
letters = ""
words = line.split()
for word in words:
    letters = letters + word[0]
print(" ".join(letters))

String = I have a dog
Result: I h a d
```

To print the result like this:

```
I
h
a
d
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your print statement for this one

```
print("\n".join(letters))
```

`\n` is the new line character, that's why.

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity, you can reduce the code to the:

```
line = input("String: ")
letters = map(lambda word: word[0], line.split())
print("\n".join(letters))
```

Answer (score 0):

On top of @Capies' answer. You can simplify the code to:

```
>>> x = "what is foo bar"
>>> "\n".join([i[0] for i in x.split()])
'w\ni\nf\nb'
```

Which prints as

```
>>> print('w\ni\nf\nb')
w
i
f
b
```

---

Explanation:

```
[i[0] for i in x.split()]
```

- `i[0]` is the first letter of each word in `x`
- As `for i in x.split()` is the iteration of words in the string `x`

And you then `join` each letter with a newline charater `\n` with `"\n".join`

Answer (score -1):

Using list comprehension.

```
[print(word[0]) for word in input().split()]
```